# Sqlalchemy/MySQL - Lazy scroll loading in database perspective

Tags: mysql, sql

I meant lazy scroll loading to refer to mechanics used in Facebook and Twitter, where by scrolling to the bottom of the page, the client makes an Ajax request to fetch next set of rows.

The first thing that comes in my mind is to use LIMIT/OFFSET on the query result. For instance,

```
+----+--------+
| id | entry  |
+----+--------+
| 25 | apple  |
| 24 | orange |
| 23 | banana |
| 22 | peach  |
| 21 | pear   |
| 20 | tomato |
+----+--------+
```

This query result is filtered by recency. (There may be multiple way to filter the outcome.)

- LIMIT 0 3 would return apple, orange, and banana.
- The next query, LIMIT 3 3 would return peach, pear, tomato.

However, if the data are added frequently, in theory this would happen.

```
+----+--------+
| id | entry  |
+----+--------+
| 27 | mango  |
| 26 | lemon  |
| 25 | apple  |
| 24 | orange |
| 23 | banana |
| 22 | peach  |
| 21 | pear   |
| 20 | tomato |
+----+--------+
```

- LIMIT 0 3 queried before lemon and mango are added. Returns apple, orange, and banana.
- LIMIT 3 3 queried after lemon and mango are added. Returns orange, banana, and peach.

Then, the client would display items in this order: apple->orange->banana->orange->banana->peach.

I only based this outcome in pure theory, so if this isn't the way it works in reality, please give me all the downvotes I deserve. At least an hour search on Google/Stack Overflow didn't give me the satisfying result.

But if my assumption is correct, that means the next query must be made based on the last record loaded, which means after apple, orange, and banana are returned, the next query should use the id of banana to fetch peach, pear, and tomato. Here are the questions.

1. How do I do that in MySQL query, finding appropriate OFFSET y to use LIMIT x OFFSET y based on id?
2. What should you do if id is deleted between two queries?

(If possible, could anyone tell me how to achieve this using sqlalchemy?)